# Output value of array rather than memory address of array

Tags: c++, arrays, polynomials

So I've made a basic polynomial class in C++ which stores the coefficients of these polynomials dynamically on the heap.  I'm currently in the process of overloading operators so that I can add/subtract polynomials together in order to simplify them etc. 
However I'm getting unexpected results when I try to overload the * operator. It looks like instead of returning the value of an index in the array it is returning the position of the array.
This is my *operator method in my .cpp file:

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator*(Polynomial p) {
int maxDegree = (degree)+(p.degree - 1);
int *intArray3 = new int[maxDegree];
int i, j;
for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < p.degree; j++) {
        cout << getCoef(i) << " * " << p.getCoef(j) << " = " << getCoef(i)*p.getCoef(j) << endl;
        intArray3[j] += (getCoef(i))*(p.getCoef(j));
        cout << " intArray3[" << j << "] contains : " << intArray3[j] << endl;
    }
}
return Polynomial(maxDegree, intArray3);}
```

The lines:

```
cout << getCoef(i) << " * " << p.getCoef(j) << " = " << getCoef(i)*p.getCoef(j) << endl;
```

and

```
cout << " intArray3[" << j << "] contains : " << intArray3[j] << endl;
```

return

```
10 * 1 = 10
intArray3[0] contains : -842150441
```

in my console. I'm assuming that the problem lies with my use of pointers somewhere but I can't for the life of me think why. I implemented this overload in a similar way to my + and - overloads and they work fine. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: You aren't initializing the values in the array, so `intArray3[j] += (getCoef(i))*(p.getCoef(j));` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: using c-style arrays invokes all kind of undesired behaviour, its easier to use `std::vector` (and harder to get wrong if you do)

Comment: @UnholySheep you were right, initialising the values fixed the problem, thank you very much